# Wifi down with Android 6.0.1, errors in 'adb logcat'

Tags: wi-fi, system-error

I thave these errors when I try to switch 'on' the wifi :

```
09-12 22:46:04.850  2590  2590 D HotspotTile: onReceive : android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED
09-12 22:46:04.850  2590  2906 D NetworkController: onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED flg=0x4000010 bqHint=4 (has extras) }
09-12 22:46:04.850  2562  2843 D PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getDataEnabled: subId=1 phoneId=0
09-12 22:46:04.850  2590  2590 D HotspotTile: onReceive : 4, 0
09-12 22:46:04.850  2562  2843 D PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getDataEnabled: subId=1 retVal=true
09-12 22:46:04.850  1814  2530 D ConnectivityManager: getMobileDataEnabled()- subId=1 retVal=true
09-12 22:46:04.870  1814  2527 E WifiController: Wi-Fi driver is unstable. Received CMD_STATEMACHINE_RESET
09-12 22:46:04.870  1814  2527 D SecContentProvider: insert(), uri = 2
09-12 22:46:04.870  1814  3831 D SecContentProvider: query(), uri = 18 selection = isWifiEnabled
09-12 22:46:04.880  1814  2818 D SecContentProvider2: query(), uri = 20 selection = isWifiStateChangeAllowed
09-12 22:46:04.890 16726 16726 D WifiSettings: >>> ERROR_ACTION RECEIVED code:10
09-12 22:46:04.890  1814  3562 D SecContentProvider2: query(), uri = 20 selection = getAllowUserProfiles
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.samsung.helphub
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:259)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at com.android.settings.Utils.isSupportHelpMenu(Utils.java:3743)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings.addOptionsMenuItems(WifiSettings.java:2204)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings.onCreateOptionsMenu(WifiSettings.java:2015)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:2376)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:2049)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentController.java:266)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3148)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:661)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:1042)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:350)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
09-12 22:46:04.910 16726 16726 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Any clue to be able to recover wifi network ?

Comment: Difficult to answer that without knowing what you did. From that logcat says wifi module is unstable and package manager can't find Samsung help hub.

Comment: I just try to put wifi ON